# An adjective for "extremely naive, almost dumb"

Tags: synonyms

Is there a single word (adjective) in English to describe an extremely naive (almost dumb) person?

**Example 1**: you get a phishing email or an email with a malware attachment - you'd want to tell the sender "Are you so [naive] to believe I am going to open it?" or "Do you think I am [naive] enough to open it?".

**Example 2**: your colleague lends a significant amount of money to their friend, knowing that the person had never returned any borrowed money before. "Were you [naive] enough to believe you'd get your money back from him?"

I would accept slang, informal word as long as it is not vulgar.

Comment: *gullible* - easily persuaded to believe something (Google); easily deceived or cheated (Dictionary.com). Works in (2) better than (1).

Comment: @Silenus I would say that that is the answer plain and simple.

Comment: @Artur, are you suggesting that the phisher - who has sent the email - or a recipient of the email who opens it is naïve? Because gullible would work for a recipient and for example 2 but not for the phisher, they're definitely not gullible, they're cleverly getting people's bank details.

Comment: @Silenus I don't think it works for the first one. Neither does any synonym of "naive" for that matter. To be honest, people sending malwares do not think it's gonna work, they just hope someone will be "naive" enough to fall for it. They have no delusion about it though (for the most part). Maybe a word like "**arrogant**", "**confident**", "**presumptuous**" or any synonym would work in that case.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Yes, in certain situations I would say so. For instance: in your private account inbox you get a scam mail sent from a person whom you've never heard of, with an "urgent service contract extension attached for countersign". Don't you think it's naive on both ends?

Comment: I agree there seems to be no word to cover both cases satisfyingly. *Gullible* is great in (2). But in (1), you'd want a word like *ignorant* or *thick*, both of which are pejorative.

Comment: I agree with @Morgan (and Silenus, I see). _Gullible_ doesn’t work for example 1A (not so well for example 2 either, unless part of the context is that your colleague’s friend actively persuaded your colleague that he’d pay the money back). 1A and 1B differ in that the _recipient_ of a phishing e-mail is in effect subject to some kind of attempted persuasion by the sender, whereas the _sender_ is not being persuaded by anyone. _Gullible_ means ‘easily persuaded to believe something’, which works for the recipient, but not for the sender.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree, in the case of 1., the person would be more *stupid* than *naive*. "Naive" is based on beliefs, "stupid" more on facts. And the fact is, he hasn't paid anyone back. "**Stupid**" would work for both sentences, as it is a general pejorative word that covers many cases. For the first sentence, the fact is that most people will not fall for it, so why would I?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (MorganFR, Silenus) : I understand that there may not be a suitable adjective in English to cover all my examples. In Polish we have one versatile metaphoric word (meaning a "deer") that we use to indicate such a person, whether they act based on beliefs, facts, or carelessness. Thanks to all who responded!

Comment: How about *Trump-supporter* ?

Answer (score 3):

How about **foolish**? It seems to work well in the examples and connotes some degree of *naivete* and *dumbness*.

> Example 1: you get a phishing email or an email with a malware
>   attachment - you'd want to tell the sender "Are you so **foolish** to
>   believe I am going to open it?" or "Do you think I am **foolish**
>   enough to open it?".
>
> Example 2: your colleague lends a significant amount of money to their
>   friend, knowing that the person had never returned any borrowed money
>   before. "Were you **foolish** enough to believe you'd get your money
>   back from him?"

From Merriam-Webster:

> **foolish**: lacking in sense, judgment, or discretion

Answer (score 0):

***Crazy, insane*** and even ***mad*** work in both of your examples.

Example 1:

> you get a phishing email or an email with a malware attachment - you'd
> want to tell the sender "Are you so ***crazy/insane/mad*** to believe I am going to
> open it?" or "Do you think I am ***crazy/insane/mad*** enough to open it?".

Example 2:

> your colleague lends a significant amount of money to their friend,
> knowing that the person had never returned any borrowed money before.
> "Were you ***crazy/insane/mad*** enough to believe you'd get your money back from
> him?"

Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[crazy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crazy)** *adjective* (NOT SENSIBLE)
>
> **stupid** or **not reasonable**:
>
> You're crazy to buy a house without seeing it.
>
> You can't be thinking of buying that old place - you're crazy!
>
> **[insane](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insane)**
> *adjective* ​​
>
> **extremely unreasonable** or **stupid**:
>
> It would be insane not to take advantage of this opportunity.
>
> **[mad](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mad)** *adjective* (SILLY) UK *informal* US *usually* crazy
>
> extremely silly or stupid:
>
> [ + to infinitive ] You're mad to walk home alone at this time of
> night.
>
> He must be mad spending all that money on a coat.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your examples there is really no need to use anything but the word "naive". As for slang terms, you could say "Did you think I was born yesterday?"